# Cascading waterfall text css

Tags: html, css

How can I make the text inside a div look something like this? I used word break and width but it's inconsistent with all other text div.

```
This is text meant to give you and example so                                                                    
 just notice how the second line has less 
   third line has less than the second
```

Answer (score 1):

Achieving this with pure css can only be done in one way, which is by using [CSS Shapes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Shapes) Not `Clip-path`.

However shapes as we know are doesn't much support across browsers, also it's not gonna be responsive, and have to deal with fixed heights/widths.

In the example below i achieved this to some extent.

Back in the day if we want text to wrap around an img we just float it without `clear:both` so the float pushes the text to wrap around the `img` even with that you can still see the edges of the box containing the `img` is we have a rounded `img` etc.

having two element in the shape of a triangle on each side and floating them makes the text go in between, just like with the `img` and it gives a waterfall text effect, however i had to hardcore the height of the two elements because `100%` requires the parent to have a height, which in this case the div does relay on it's content's height which is the text.

needs some tweaking.

```css
.main {
  width: 510px;
  height: 130px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  border: 1px solid;
  background: red;
  text-align: justify;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
}

.right {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  shape-outside: polygon(100% 0, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <p>This is text meant to give you and example so                                                                    
 just notice how the second line has less 
   third line has less than the second.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.textAlign{
text-align:center;
}
.textAlign ul{
list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
  

<div class="textAlign">
    <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
     <li>This is text meant to give you and example so</li>                                                               
     <li>just notice how the second line has less </li>
     <li> third line has less than the second</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe she wants it to continue to cascade without using <br> or css widths. My recommendation would be to create a script that adds a line break automatically every nth word. Then the nth number has a -- to it so at first it might have a line break after 10 words, then 8 and so on.

Comment: try now using Ul And li